# Values in the Global environment vs Data R

Tags: r, environment

Why are Values visible in the Global Environment, but not accessible like data in the "Data" section? For example, I can view a table in the Data section, but not values objects in the Values section. They seem different in other ways as well.

Comment: your question is poorly constructed  ,could you provide an example of what you meant

Comment: The reasons for why is not clear to me, maybe it's about the complexity of showing data structures other than a two-dimensional array.

Comment: @Richard Scriven Jokes...in the Global Environment window in R Studio I have a "Data" section that contains data.frames which I can view by hitting the table icon at the right. There is another section called "Values" that also has objects that are said to be data.frames however there is no table icon at the right. Why are objects in these 2 sections different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you are looking at something like this:

[image]

The "Data" item `npk` shows that the MASS package has an .Rdata file that holds that item and it is loaded into the workspace with the `data` function when the package gets loaded from the Library. You can look at it using the console:

```
> str(npk)
'data.frame':   24 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ block: Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ N    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ P    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ K    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 ...
 $ yield: num  49.5 62.8 46.8 57 59.8 58.5 55.5 56 62.8 55.8 ...
```

If you click on the tiny table-icon over on the right side of that pane in the same row as the name of the dataframe, the values will appear in the "viewer"-window. The same effect can be achieved with `View(npk)` from the console-pane. The other items below 'npk' labeled as "promises" will each become more instantiated or "real" in the Environment pane when they are accessed by your console commands or functions:

```
> View(npk)
> str(abbey)
 num [1:31] 5.2 6.5 6.9 7 7 7 7.4 8 8 8 ...
> accdeaths[1]
[1] 9007
```

So now that pane looks like:

[image]

The "promises" have been fulfilled! R is actually a pass-by-promise language (very much like pass-by-value and *not* like pass-by-refernce) and so sometimes variable names may exist in the workspace before they are actually called into being, i.e. evaluated.